# Images database/API service of all major cities

Tags: gratis, database, php, api, json

Hope this is not off-topic as [asking for data-sources](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I am developing an app for flights booking and status, I have everything ready but I would like to have an image displaying for each major city in the world e.g:

User searches **Rome**, show
[image]
, **San Francisco**
[image] and so on...

Obviously each image should be of the same height and width.

So is there some database/API-service which I can use to retrieve those images using the city code (Metropolitan Area) e.g. **ROM** for Rome, **QSF** for San Francisco or airport code e.g. **JFK** for John F. Kennedy International Airport in New York (US), **LCY** for London City Airport in London (UK)?

**Note**: If you know an API-service I need it to be in JSON, instead if you know a DB it must be MySQL or SQL based

Comment: I am looking for something similar. Did you manage to find anything good?

Comment: No @tutak, I'm sorry...I think I'm gonna start a bounty on this question to draw attention

Comment: I started using the following API, I found it pretty good although the choice of cities is limited and some of the images are not of the highest quality: https://developers.teleport.org/api/getting_started/#photos_ua

Comment: Wow thank you for reporting! It's better than nothing.If you want you can post it as an answer to this question

Comment: Di niente! Answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Teleport API](http://developers.teleport.org/api/getting_started/#photos_ua). Some of the images are not of great quality and choice of cities is limited but definitely worth a shot.

Comment: Why is teleport API 403 error?